# Going deeper in my http request will not show the needed data on the view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

So building up on the previous question ([Http request in service successful but not able to show in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151122/http-request-in-service-successful-but-not-able-to-show-in-view?noredirect=1#33151198)). I need to go deeper in my http request to make a api call for a selected movie, like so:

```
http.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/'+ movieId + '?api_key=XXX')
```

Full code of my service:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.service('HotMoviesService', function($http, $q){
    var movieId;
    var final_url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=XXX";

    var self = {
        'hotMovies' : [],
        'singleHotMovie' : [],
        'loadHotMovies' : function() {
            var d = $q.defer();
            $http.get(final_url)
            .success(function success (data){
                //console.log(data);
                self.hotMovies = data.results;

                for(var i = 0; i < self.hotMovies.length; i++){
                    //console.log(self.hotMovies[i].id);
                    movieId = self.hotMovies[i].id;
                    //console.log("Logging movie id: ", movieId);

                    $http.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/'+ movieId + '?api_key=XXXXX')
                    .success(function succcess(response){
                        //console.log("Logging response in the for loop " , response);
                        self.singleHotMovie = response;
                    })
                    .error(function error (msg){
                        console.log(msg);
                    })
                }

                d.resolve('The promise has been fulfilled');
            })
            .error(function error (msg){
                console.error("There was an error retrieving the data " , msg);
                d.reject("The promise was not fulfilled");
            });
            return d.promise;
        }
    };
    return self;
})
```

My controller is the following:

```
.controller('StartCtrl', function($scope, $http, HotMoviesService) {

//POPULAR
    $scope.hotmovies = [];

    HotMoviesService.loadHotMovies().then(function success (data){
        console.log(data);//returns success message saying that promise is fulfilled
        $scope.hotmovies = HotMoviesService.singleHotMovie;
    },
    function error (data){
        console.log(data)//returns error messag saying that promise is not fulfilled
    });
})
```

HTML code (list of movies)

```
<ion-view view-title="The Movie Bank">
  <ion-content class="background">

    <h1 class="padding titleStart">Welcome to The Movie Bank</h1>
    <div class="logo"></div>

    <!-- HOT -->
    <a class="customHref" href="#/app/hot">
        <h1 class="padding customH1">Hot</h1>
    </a>

    <hscroller>
        <ion-scroll direction="x" scrollbar-x="false">
            <hcard ng-repeat="hotmovie in hotmovies"> 
                <a href="#/app/hot/{{hotmovie.id}}">
                    <img ng-src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92/{{hotmovie.poster_path}}" >
                </a>
            </hcard>
        </ion-scroll>
    </hscroller>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

When clicking on one of the movies it should go to the detail page which is does (the id is shown in the url), but i can't seem to read out data for that specific movie. Although all my request are ok and coming through in my console.

HTML code for details page:

```
<ion-view view-title="Hot Detail">
  <ion-content >
    <h1>test</h1>
    <h4>{{original_title}}</h4>
    <img ng-src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92/{{hotMovie.poster_path}}" >
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Screenshot of the details page:
[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: FWIW, `success` and `error` are deprecated. But isn't this just an async issue? E.g., you're setting a value in the callback, and trying to use it before it even finishes?

Comment: @DaveNewton, i don't believe its an async issue... but then again not 100% sure. pretty new at it all

Comment: Your `d.resolve('The promise has been fulfilled');` is at the end of the _loadHotMovies_ function, not within the first-level's `$http.get`'s _success_ callback, meaning you can be outputting "The promise has been fulfilled" before it fully has completed; rather, your $q.deferred (_d_) will be completed, but not the _$http_ call.

Comment: @EricMcCormick, mmm if i leave out the whole code of the for loop then the promise get fulfilled (data comes through in my console). see previous post  Http request in service successful but not able to show in view . I am just expanding the code so i believe my d.resolve is not the issue

Comment: That certainly cleared up what I was seeing, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message "The promise has been fulfilled" is shown, so you know the first request went ok, but that doesn't tell you anything about the moviedetail-calls.

You enter a loop to retrieve all the "hot movie" details. However, since the `d.resolve` is in the success code of the first call, the promise is resolved before your moviedetails calls are done.

I would make an array of promisses (from all the detail calls) and use `$q.all(promises);` to resolve when all these calls are done. That way you know all your data is in.

One more thing...

You copy the response to self.singleHotMovie in `self.singleHotMovie = response;`. 
That way, only the very last movie-details call to resolve will be in self.singleHotMovie. You might want to use `self.singleHotMovie.push(response)` to add it to the array instead.

**untested:**

```
'loadHotMovies' : function() {
        var d = $q.defer();
        $http.get(final_url)
        .success(function success (data){
            //console.log(data);
            self.hotMovies = data.results;

            // create an array to hold the prommisses
            var promisses = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < self.hotMovies.length; i++){

                //console.log(self.hotMovies[i].id);
                movieId = self.hotMovies[i].id;
                //console.log("Logging movie id: ", movieId);

                var promise = $http.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/'+ movieId + '?api_key=XXXXX')
                .success(function succcess(response){
                    //console.log("Logging response in the for loop " , response);
                    self.singleHotMovie = response;
                })
                .error(function error (msg){
                    console.log(msg);
                });
                // add all the detail calls to the promise array
                promisses.push(promise);
            }

            //when all the details calls are resolved, resolve the parent promise
            $q.all(promisses).finally(function(){
                d.resolve('The promise has been fulfilled');
            });
        })
        .error(function error (msg){
            console.error("There was an error retrieving the data " , msg);
            d.reject("The promise was not fulfilled");
        });
        return d.promise;
    }
```

Comment: ok i understand what your saying but implementing it code wise not completely, especially the part about an array of promises. can you give a code example. much appreciated

Comment: thanks for the quick response and code. I implemented your code. But is there not something more i should be doing in the details view. to show the data

Comment: logging the var promise in the for loop gives me this -> https://gyazo.com/be0a2ccdae9c47a7fe4a3d177674e58e . so we now know that works but i am still not able to show my data on details pages ..

Comment: the promise is being resolved on the details page but i am still not able to show any data ... -> https://gyazo.com/6b6f0f28178b27013a04eaae3d2e278e . its so frustrating ... :-(

Comment: I'll have a look at it tonight. Can you make a jsfiddle with your non working code? I'm sure i'll be something small we're not seeing. 
In the meanwhile, here's an example of the use of $q.all:
http://jsfiddle.net/jkrielaars/nduko02k/4/

Comment: i tried to do it in jsfiddle, but did not know how to add multiple html en js files. so i think the easiest way is to give you a zip of my project (its very small, cause i only just started). maybe tonight we can open a chat on stack and i can give it like that to you. sorry for any inconvience

Comment: The twitter account from your profile does not exist. how can I contact you outside of the public stack overflow?

Comment: sorry there was a typo in my twitter name. now i fixed it.